# configuring dedicated internet access

Tags: networking, ip, isp

I have taken a dedicated internet access service from my ISP. for which i received one P2P IP  address with a specified gateway, and 6 IP addresses on a /29 subnet. but they havent specified any gateway for these 6 addresses. Further, they say that is an internal range for my account. What does this mean? that these 6 addresses are not public IPs? if so, how do I configure them  ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did and all the info they gave me, is what I've put up. I've asked to talk to a senior level support guy to help on this matter, but no response so far. I was wondering maybe if I could do this on my own without having to wait for their reply. I tried looking for similar scenarios online, and maybe someone who has used a similar service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you have a P2P (/30) address between your router and the ISP equipment?

Internal range usually just means that they will be routing the /29 subnet towards your routers P2P IP address.

You'd need to assign the /29 to an interface pointing towards your LAN on the router using one of the ip addresses in the range. Then you can assign the remaining addresses to hosts with a default gateway of whatever address you just assigned on your router interface towards the LAN.

Comment: ok,so that means they are not actually public ip addresses, and i will have to do port forwarding from the P2P address to this range which i have been given so that i can host whatever service i need.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean they aren't public ip addresses. It is a common practice for addresses to be provided this way. Do the addresses fall within the RFC address space? (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16)

Comment: No, they are in the 62.x.x.x address space

Comment: @BahrainAdmin Why do you think they're not actually public IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Five of those addresses can be assigned to hosts. One of those IP addresses should be assigned to your router. The gateway for the 5 of those addresses not assigned to your router is the one you do assign to the router. The gateway for your router is the gateway they gave you.

Comment: ok,so that means they are not actually public ip addresses, and i will have to do port forwarding from the P2P address to this range which i have been given so that i can host whatever service i need

Comment: They're public IP addresses. You don't have to do port forwarding. This is how normal routing is done.